# WebView java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to modify given thread

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, securityexception

I have an application that uses multiple WebViews. Nowhere do I set the priority of the render thread through the WebSettings though I still get the exception below.

So far it only seems to happen on android 4.0.4, which I haven't found the source code for.

Anyone run into this and/or knows a solution? Thanks!

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to modify given thread
at android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Native Method)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:712)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:789)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: I have run into it, in a stack trace from a crash from an app of mine in the field. I have not been able to reproduce it, and I haven't the foggiest notion why it happened.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one. Android 4.0.4 only as well?

Comment: Yes, although in my case, it was from a Samsung Capitvate, which (AFAICT) does not have an official ICS release, so I can't tell if it's "real" or if it's a problem with some ROM mod.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's cyanogen's fault. https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/commit/b963f3c0c64560bcdb1596dd85fe9b0dad6d78c5#L1R712

I have a pile of crash reports on this issue, all from 4.0.4 on many different devices, all of them likely running some form of CM9 (most don't have official ICS releases yet).

I don't have time to yell at them, so hopefully someone else can bring it up in their bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you, I filed an issue in their bugtracker http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=5656&thanks=5656&ts=1341224425